# According to the naming of other tags, shouldn't the tag amigashell be changed to amiga-shell?

Tags: support, retag-request

It looks like two words in a tag are not "writtentogether" instead "written-thisway", right?

Comment: You're going to thrive here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acording to other name tags, there shouldn't be an Amiga-Shell tag at all. A shell is something that each and every OS provides in some way. For a good reason there is no  Windows-Shell, Atari-ST-Shell, Atari-800-Shell, MS-DOS-Shell or Unix-Shell tag, but a tag for each of the systems/OSes plus the Shell tag.

Tags are meant to help finding stuff, that means they must be rather inclusive, not not maximum differentiating (excluding).

Looking at the questions that are, so far, tagged with Amiga-Shell, all of them are tagged with Amiga as well.

So no, **better remove that tag at all and replace it by 'Shell' in these six questions**.

Answer (score 1):

Yup. I'm just going to go ahead and unilaterally rename it now, since it's so easy to revert.

[amigashell](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amigashell) → [amiga-shell](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amiga-shell)

8 revision history entries, 6 questions and 3 "favourite tag" entries were adjusted, so the impact won't have been too big.

Comment: Thanks.
Also, only one question uses the tag "a-3000". Since all other questions regarding Amiga models starts the tag amiga-, could you remove the a-3000 tag so the tag amiga-3000 is used instead.

Comment: @OlaStröm I'll synonymise it, so anyone who makes the mistake in future doesn't make a new tag by mistake.

Comment: @OlaStröm Done. You're really going to improve the site if you carry on like this.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 For me, A3000 means the Archimedes A3000 (https://www.retro-kit.co.uk/page.cfm/content/Acorn-BBC-A3000/). Could this synonym be an issue for future questions about the Archimedes?

Comment: @Kaz Yeah, that makes more sense. I'll remove the synonym. Do you want to make a question about the A3000?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 By all means, and as a habitual Acorn user, I'll do my best to answer it. :) Though an "Archimedes" tag may be more useful, as there were over a dozen Archimedes models, of which the A3000 was one.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Sorry, I mis-read your post, and thought you wrote "do you want me to make a question". I'll get a question on the board for the A3000 or Archimedes sometyime soon.